# Trigger a keyup event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, listener

I am having serious issues with my code that's being injected by a Chrome extension that I'm creating. Essentially, I need a keyup event listener to pickup a certain key but I can't seem to get it.

Here's the code that I'm injecting (Note that there is a lot of redundancy because I'm trying tons of things to get it to trigger the event listener, I will clean this up once I find the code that works).

```
function simulateKey(iElement) {
    $( iElement ).focus();

    var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
    e.which = 37;
    e.keyCode = 37;
    e.charCode = 0;

    $( iElement ).keyup(function () {
        console.log("keyup element");
    });

    $( iElement ).trigger(e);

    var f = jQuery.Event("keyup");
    f.which = 70;
    e.keyCode = 70;
    f.ctrlKey = true;
    f.shiftKey = true;

    $( iElement ).trigger(f);
    $ ( document ).trigger(f);
    $ ( window ).trigger(f);    
}
```

When this function is called, the input element becomes focused and "keyup element" is printed to the console. But when this function is called and I have an Event Listener Breakpoint set for keyup events, the code never breaks out.

When I simply press a key on my keyboard while focused inside the input field and I have an Event Listener Breakpoint set for keyup events, there is a break in the source jquery.min.js and "(e)" is highlighted, which is the parameter for this function call: "f=v.handle=function(e)"... Take note that only one breakpoint happens normally, but if I have already called my function, then 2 breakpoints happen because I'm generating that console.log on keyup events.

Any help is extremely appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$.Event()` to create the requested event and than use `.trigger()`.

DEMO: [**JSnippet**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/298/Trigger-a-keypresskeydownkeyup-event-in-JSjQuery)

CODE:

```
$(function() {
    var $iElement = $('#logit');
    $iElement.keyup(function(e) {
      console.log(e.which);
      $(this).val(e.which);
    });
    simulateKey($iElement);
});


function simulateKey($iElement) {
    var e = $.Event('keyup');
    e.which = 65; // Character 'A'
    $iElement.trigger(e);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that even the code you give me does seem to be picked up by other keyup listeners. If you go to your JSnippet page, open dev tools and set an Event Breakpoint for keyup events, it won't break when you run the code even though e.which is printed to the console and set as the value in iElement. But, if you focus the html input and start typing, the breakpoint triggers.